# UserAgent String information for knowing the plugins or extensions installed on the requesting browser?

Tags: user-agent

Can the details about installed **plugins** or **extensions** found by inspecting UserAgent string? I tried installing many plugins but I could not seen any of its reflection in the user agent string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) site.

It has many user agents. I went through many Useragents and finally I could see that in older browser versions of **IE** and **Opera** the name of the *plugins/extensions* were present.

In **Chrome** and **Firefox** I could not find any such imprints.

Answer (score 3):

The UserAgent string won't contain any information about the plugins or extensions installed on the client's browser.  It is simply a depiction of the version of the browser the user has.  If you are looking for the capabilities of the browser, try looking into [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) and checking out what capabilities it can test for.

Comment: But from the UserAgent strings of Internet Explorer, I found some details about the installed extensions, such as Download Managers.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the extensions in Chrome or Firefox are JavaScript based. If an extension is interacting with the page, it will most likely be using JavaScript. So depending on what extensions you're trying to detect, you might be able to detect them with JavaScript on the page. A lot of them, though, will have code encased in a separate context, so that may be difficult.

Here's a [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication) from Google's plugin guide about content scripts.